# Karate API Test Debugging in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, karate

This is sort of an open-ended question/request (hope that's allowed).

On my team we are using Karate API testing for our project, which we love. The tests are easy to write and fairly understandable to people without coding backgrounds. The biggest problem we're facing is that these API tests have some inherent degree of flakiness (since the code we're testing makes calls to other systems). When running the tests locally on my machine, it's easy to see where the test failed. However, we're also using a Jenkins pipeline, and when the tests fail in Jenkins it's difficult to see why/how they failed. By default we get a message like this:

```
com.company.api.OurKarateTests > [crossdock] Find Crossdock Location.[1:7] LPN is invalid FAILED

    com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException
```

Basically all this tells us is the file name and starting line of the scenario that failed. We do have our pipeline set up so that we can pass in a `debug` flag and get more information. There are two problems with this however; one is that you have to remember to put in this flag in every commit you want to see info on; the other is that we go from having not enough information to too much (reading through a 24MB file of the whole build).

What I'm looking for is suggestions on how to improve this process, preferably without making changes to the Jenkins pipeline (another team manages this, and it will likely take a long time). Though if changing the pipeline is the only way to do this, I'd like to know that. I'm willing to "think outside the box" and entertain unorthodox solutions (like, posting to a slack integration).

We're currently on Karate version 0.9.3, but I will probably plan to upgrade to 0.9.5 as part of this effort. I've read a bit about the changes. Would the "ExecutionHook" thing be a good way to do this? I will be experimenting with this on my own a bit.

Have other teams/devs faced this issue? What were your solutions? Again we really love Karate, just struggling with the integration of it to Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you using the Cucumber Reporting library as described here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report

If you do - you will get an HTML report with all traffic (and anything you `print`) in-line with the test-steps, and of-course error traces, and most teams find this sufficient for build troubleshooting, there is no need to dig through logs.

Do try upgrade as well, because we keep trying to improve the usefulness of the logs, and you may see improvements if you had failed in a JS block or `karate-config.js`.

Else, yes the `ExecutionHook` would be a good thing to explore - but I would be really surprised if the HTML report does not give you what you need.